# How to run Pyspark standalone program at ec2 in the background?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have written PySpark code locally. Now I want to push the code into the EC2 and run it in a Standalone mode. But if i run the code with spark-submit program was occupying terminal. But I have to use the terminal to work with other things.

I thought Running PySpark in background or as daemon was solution but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are higher level solutions like Airflow or Livy that you can submit/schedule Spark jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways.

1. Nohup
2. Cron

nohup command(spark-submit coommand) &

this will execute your spark job in background.

you have to write your spark code in python file (.py file) and submit that using spark-submit in nohup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sachin, i have tried Nohup and i was working fine. Does Cron work the same was as Nohup ?